# Python/Pygame Elif Syntax Error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make the snake game using Python 3.6.1 and pygame. But, when I run it the section where i handle the controls it just bugs out. I have looked over the code three times and could not find a problem. Here's the code.

```
'while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.quit()
elif event.type == pygame.KEY_DOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.KEY == ord('d'):
            changeto = 'RIGHT'
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                changeto = 'left'
        if event.key == pygame.KEY_UP or == ord('w'):
                        changeto = 'up'
        if event.key == pygame.KEY_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                            changeto = 'down'
        if event.key == pygame.KEY_ESCAPE:
        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))'
```

Comment: You do notice the mis-indented `elif` right?

Comment: Indent it.......

Comment: Oh, thanks. I always forget about indenting certain things, thanks!

Comment: @Caleb.H It is a bit too optimistic to use graphical libraries if you have trouble with indention. It'll be very exhausting for you if you try creating something big (like a graphical game) without having good enough understanding on the essentials of Python. It might cause you to lose motivation quite quickly, which it does with many potential programmers. If you instead try to watch beginners tutorials and develop more simple programs, you'll probably learn more and keep the ambition higher for longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the intention of the else block of the condition:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

```
'while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        ....  
    elif event.type == pygame.KEY_DOWN:
        .....
```